# Where to get Java.media package?

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, jcreator

I am making a java applet player. It includes Java.Media package, and I am not getting it. Searched on the google to download it but all in vain.

a piece of code is here

```
import javax.media.*;

    AxisPlayer mPlayer;
    mPlayer = new AxisPlayer(videoWidth, videoHeight, mFps,mUrl.openStream());
```

This is what I want to do but I don't have Javax.media package.

so my question is :

Q : From where to download the Java.media package and how to install it from Jcreator/NetBeans

Remember, I am using JDK 1.6.0.

Thanks in anticipation for helping me.

Comment: Have a look for the Java Media Framework.

Comment: @EJP :: I have downloaded a file with the name "jmf-2_1_1e-windows-i586" while searching to get the java.media package.

I installed it and it done successfully but my problem not resolved even after downloading and installing it.

Comment: Your problem being what? [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Java Media API](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/)**

You are looking for [java.media.*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR)

Comment: I am making a applet player to play a video file.

Comment: I have already downloaded JMF 2.1.1e Software from the link mentioned by you, installed it but what to do next, I don't know. My problem stands as it is even after installing this software.

Comment: @azeemAkram What you actually need is the `jmf-2_1_1e-alljava.zip` in which you will find a folder 'lib'. This folder contains a bunch of jar files which you need to add to the build path in your Java project. The jar `jmf.jar` contains your 'javax.media.*', but I guess you need most of the other jars as well for dependencies (just try it out).

Answer (score 0):

Look man here is the link from where you can just download the Java Media Framework

It's hosted on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html